How to wait a server for SSL handshake using Curl?
I need get a website using Curl but the server does not respond the SSL connection and Curl says an error on the 2 minutes but the server respond in the minute ~5. I try to use the timeout argument but the arguments works only for the HTTP response, not for SSL connection, my command is:
time curl --max-time 300 --connect-timeout 300 \
    https://certificacioninternacional.mijp.gob.ve/paginas/CU_registrarUsuario/;

Response:
curl: (28) Failed to connect to certificacioninternacional.mijp.gob.ve
 port 443 after 134660 ms: Couldn't connect to server

real    2m14.665s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.007s

In the Wireshark the syn tcp request is not respond with the ack, but if wait ~5 minutes the server respond in fewer times.

I try read the local os setting using:
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries
6

But in the Wireshark I see 10 times.
How to await to server response ack before Curl timeout without a time limit without develop a low level app? With Node.JS and Python have same problem but in Google Chrome works.

This website an intranet website? Website absolutely doesn’t return any response with a browser

If use http to send form server says an error and redirect to https, but the get request return a 403, but the post return a 200, for normal get requests need a http connection but the post works only with https. The browser load website 1 or 2 times per day aprox, i try made a bot for wait the connection multiple times but have the timeout problem and sync retries.
